# Loading property file for maven-surefire-plugin

Tags: java, maven

I have a *testng* class which tests a class which in turns load property from classpath.When i run maven install i am getting an error mentioning file not found.It is not able to find the property file though i have it in `src/test/resources`. How to resolve this issue?

the java code is having a constructor which tries to load the property file `Properties props = JobUtils .loadProperties("x.properties");` my maven configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin
  <version>2.5
  <configuration>
    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

with:

```
<build>
  <testResources>
    <testResource>
      <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
      <filtering>false</filtering>
    </testResource>
  </testResources>
</build>
```

Also I have this `x.properties` in `src/test/resource`

Stack trace Running TestSuite is:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: x.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
   at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
   at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:106)
   at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:66)
```

Also note the test class i have tries to instantiate this java code and test it.

Comment: Can you provide more information, as it not enough to help you? Does `mvn test` work properly? Is the properties file part of some kind of environment/profile configuration? Can you post the stack trace and code that tries to load the properties file?

Comment: the java code is having a constructor which tries to load the property file Properties props = JobUtils
    .loadProperties("x.properties"); my maven configuration <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                   
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

Comment: with build  <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
</build> Also i have this x.properties in src/test/resource Stack trace Running TestSuite
java.io.FileNotFoundException: x.properties (The system cannot fin
d the file specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:66)

Comment: Also note the test class i have tries to instantiate this java code and test it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `x.properties` file from the `src/test/resources` directory is actually being copied to the `target/test-classes` directory after the Maven `process-test-resources` phase is executed. So if you want your application to be able to find it, you should use the following file-path:

```
Properties props = JobUtils .loadProperties("target/test-classes/x.properties");
```

However I do not think this is exactly what you are looking for. I recommend to read the property file directly from the CLASSPATH (without using the file-system directly) using a code like this:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/x.properties");
Properties p = new Properties();
try {
  p.load(is);
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  if (is != null) {
    try {
      is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Using this approach you will be able to load the property file even from within a JAR file distributed to the customer or also from a configuration file that is added to the CLASSPATH in some kind of a launch-script.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem of a file not being found. However, I got to a point where I realized that maven found it for use when I ran mvn test on the command line. It was just my Eclipse IDE telling me it can't find it. When I changed in my IDE directory src/test/resources into a "source directory", then my IDE was fine too.